# Lock table row from data modifying

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id serial int,
  col text
);

insert into t1(col) values('old_value');
```

now, I need  lock this table from data modifying, while below plsql block is running

```
DO $$
  declare 
     res1 TEXT;
     res2 TEXT;
  BEGIN 
        --PERFORM pg_advisory_lock( )  
        select col from t1 where id = 1 into  res1;
        FOR i in 1..2000000000 LOOP
           -- this is just for waiting several second
        END LOOP;
        select col from t1 where id = 1 into  res2;
        RAISE NOTICE '% - %', res1, res2;
        --PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock( )  
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

So while  this  block is running, I run other query:

```
update t1 SET col = 'new_value' where id = 1;
```

This query works immediately and updates row  when running plsql block is not completed.

I need contrary, I need that update  not worked and waited, while plsql block running.

I suppose that `pg_advisory_lock()` and  `pg_advisory_unlock()` would help, but how to use it, I don't understood, what is key parameter for these functions, I don't get it.

And also not sure, if these functions will work at all.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `select col from t1 where id = 1 FOR UPDATE into  res1;` to get the lock, so the whole block should look as following:

`DO $$
  declare 
     res1 TEXT;
     res2 TEXT;
  BEGIN 
        --PERFORM pg_advisory_lock( )

        select col from t1 where id = 1 into FOR UPDATE res1;
        FOR i in 1..2000000000 LOOP
           -- this is just for waiting several second
        END LOOP;
        select col from t1 where id = 1 into  res2;
        RAISE NOTICE '% - %', res1, res2;
        --PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock( )

  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL`

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly lock the rows in a transaction in the `SELECT` clause:

```
DO $$
  DECLARE
     res1 TEXT;
     res2 TEXT;
  BEGIN 
    SELECT col INTO res1 FROM t1 WHERE id = 1 FOR SHARE;
    pg_sleep(5); -- Sleep 5 seconds
    SELECT col INTO res2 FROM t1 WHERE id = 1;
    RAISE NOTICE '% - %', res1, res2;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Use the `FOR SHARE` clause rather than `FOR UPDATE` to allow other session to read the data, but not update.

Comment: Thank you, Now I tested and `FOR UPDATE` also allows read the data, for example I can do `select`. what you mean under: "Use the FOR SHARE clause rather than FOR UPDATE to allow other session to read the data, but not update."

Comment: The `FOR SHARE` lock is weaker than `FOR UPDATE`, basically related to the use of primary and foreign keys to other tables.